# angular2 - how to set background image in particular component

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to set background image for particular components.I want to set image to entire html page of  example.component.html, but its not working for me

example.component.css

```
html {background: url(assets/imagenew.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;    -
                   webkit-background-size: cover;  
                  -moz-background-size: cover; 
                  -o-background-size: cover;   background-size: cover; } 
 body { background-color: transparent;    
        overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: what about `ng-style` like this  `<div ng-style="{'width': '20px', 'height': '20px', ...}"></div>`

Comment: it set style to only that div

Comment: @wildDev ..its not working